# How to calculate the number of nodes in an unbalanced binary tree at a given depth

Tags: python, algorithm, math, binary-tree, nodes

I am trying to calculate the number of nodes a tree will have at a given depth if the binary tree is not balanced.

I know that in the case of a perfectly balanced, you can use 2^d to calculate the number of nodes, where d is the depth of a tree.

Assume there is a binary tree. At the root level, it only has one node. Also, assume that the root node only has one child instead of 2. So at the next depth, there is only one node instead of 2. which means that at the next depth, there will be only two nodes instead of 4. in the next depth, there will be eight instead of 16.

So yeah is there any way I can foretell the number of nodes there will be at a given depth based on the number of nodes present or not present in the previous depth.

Any kind of answer would do if there is a mathematical formula that will help. If you know a way I could do it iteratively in breadth-first search order in any programming language that would help too.

Comment: Note that in your description, there is a "regular" balanced tree there, it just starts a few nodes later, so the number of nodes is still 2^d, for the depth of _that_ tree, plus the few loose nodes above it.

Comment: Well, I used it to give an example. At different heights, it could have an arbitrary number of nodes missing at any depth which will change the count of nodes present at future depth.

Comment: Then the answer is a trivial "no"? If you don't know how many nodes are missing, you can't calculate the number of nodes except by literally counting nodes. You'll have an upper and a lower bound, anything between that depends on checking the tree itself.

Comment: I am not saying that I don't know how many nodes are missing I am saying If I know that there is 1 node less than the total number of possible nodes in the depth 1 and let's say I know that there are 3 nodes less than the total possible node at depth 3 is there way to tell how many nodes will be there at depth 4 assuming no nodes are missing i.e., every node at depth 3 has both left and right child.

Comment: please update your post to explain things the way you just did, because your post is currently talking about a situation where it sounds like you have no idea what's missing.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of nodes at depth  is , then the number of nodes at depth  + 1 lies between 0 and 2. The minimum of 0 is reached when all those nodes at depth  happen to be leaves, and the maximum of 2 is reached when all those nodes at depth  happen to have two children each.